# Uncertainty in approximated relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-technique, error-analysis

I'll give directly an example to fix the ideas. Suppose that you're studying the acceleration of a system of masses that depends from the number $n$ of masses $m$ by the following relation:

$$a=a_0+n\dfrac{m}{\mu}g.$$

Here $[a_0]=[L][T^{-2}]$ and $[\mu]=[M]$ are two costants independent from $n$. Suppose also that, in the case where the $n$ masses are different, the relation becomes:$$a=a_0 +\dfrac{\sum _{i=1}^{n} m_i}{\mu}g,$$
with the same constants.

In an experiment, I had to use a relation of this kind and, to get a linear relation, it was needed to use the first approximation, where $n\cdot m$ replaces the sum.
Clearly all masses weren't equal and I had a weighing scale enough sensible to see that.

My question is, what would be the best value $m$ to be used in the first relation and what its uncertainty?
In my specific case I had a quite symmetric distribution of values, so I took:$$m=\dfrac{m_{\text {max}}+m_{\text{min}}}{2}\pm\dfrac{m_{\text {max}}-m_{\text{min}}}{2},$$
where the uncertainty is took to include all values possible.
Is there a more precise way to do this?

**Note**: I'm not looking for the approximation of $m$ for a fixed value of $n$. I'm looking for the best approximation of $m$ that fits for all the cases $n=1,2,...,N$, where $N$ is the total number of masses.

Comment: If you're trying to choose a value _m_ that most closely satisfies _nm_ = SUM, why wouldn't you use the mean value _m_ = SUM / _n_?

Comment: It is not so simple. To use the linear relation, I have to find the best approximation for $m$ for all the cases $i=1,2,...,n$. The value $m=\Sigma/n$ is surely the best approximation (it's exact) for the case $i=n$, but what about $i=k<n$?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** completely misread the question and gave a sort of unrelated answer.  Read the bottom for my correction.

---

The reason why you can't just "add" your uncertainties is because you have to take into account that a positive error in one measurement will coincide with a negative error in another half of the time.  So if you add your uncertainties together, the new "range" is way overestimating the reasonable expected values.

If you can consider your measurement error as the result of several uncorrelated small errors (which is a practical assumption in most cases), we may model the "true" value then as a [Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), with

$$\mu = \frac{m_{max} + m_{min}}{2}$$

and

$$\sigma \approx \frac{m_{max} - m_{min}}{2}$$

(Which means that, if you take repeated precise measurements of that mass, $68\%$ of the values will fall between $m_{max}$ and $m_{min}$, $95\%$ will fall between double that range, etc.)

Normally distributed independent random variables are very well-analyzed and we know that

$$
N[\mu_1,\sigma_1] + N[\mu_2,\sigma_2] = N[\mu_1 + \mu_2,\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}]
$$

That is -- if you add together two normally distributed independent random variables -- the first with a mean $\mu_1$ and standard deviation $\sigma_1$, and the second with a mean $\mu_2$ and standard deviation $\sigma_2$, their sum will behave like one "composite"/"big" normally distributed random variable with a new mean $\mu_1 + \mu_2$ and new standard deviation $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$ (if you don't believe me, you are welcome to try it yourself with a computer simulation)

Therefore if you have $m_1 \pm \Delta m_1$ and $m_2 \pm \Delta m_2$, and $M = m_1 + m_2$, you will have

$$
M = (m_1 + m_2) \pm \Delta M
$$

$$
\Delta M = \sqrt{(\Delta m_1)^2 + (\Delta m_2)^2}
$$

And if you want the "average" mass, you'll also need the rule

$$
C \times N[\mu_0,\sigma_0] = N[C \mu_0, C \sigma_0]
$$

where $C$ in your case is $\frac{1}{2}$.

If you were really ambitious you could extend this to calculate the uncertainty in $a$, although you will run into trouble if $g$ and $\mu$ have uncertainties because it hasn't been stated here what $N[\mu_1,\sigma_1] * N[\mu_2,\sigma_2]$ becomes, nor in the division case.  Research into Error Propagation if you wish to be able to calculate the total uncertainty in $a$.

---

**CORRECTION**

So I didn't realize that the asker was only asking for the proper value of the mean of the masses taking into account different uncertainties in measurements.

In this case, the standard procedure would be to use a weighted average, weighted by 
$$\frac{1}{\Delta m_i^2}$$
for each measurement.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you. The uncertainties $\Delta m_i$ are the same for all $i$, so this reduces to the first comment to my post (see my answer).